# TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects when save machine learning model to pickle

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, model, pickle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiAMc.png)

My machine learning model is just a basic tensorflow keras CNN model, after I call model.compile and model.fit. I want to use this code to save, but failed, typeerror details is in the image. Can someone help me out? thank you!

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
model = CCNModel(X)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
r = model.fit(X, y, epochs=200)
joblib_file = "MFCNNModel.pkl"
joblib.dump(model, joblib_file)
```

Comment: You cannot save keras models as a pickle file. The preferred way of saved a model is the `SavedModel` format, achieved by `tf.saved_model.save(model, directory)`. You can also save it as a true keras model, using `tf.keras.models.save`.

Comment: @FrederikBode thanks for your response, if I want to deploy my model at the backend of my application, what's the next step if I use this way? thanks.

Comment: you can load and call your model with `model = tf.saved_model.load(directory)` and `model(input)` resp.